# SSL enabled API Authentication in R using httr

Tags: r, ssl, httr

I am trying to perform GET operation in R using httr library and I am getting this error - SSL: certificate subject name 'string' does not match target host name 'localhost".
Looking for way to resolve the same.

I am using below code :

```
set_config(config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L )) 
URL <- "https://localhost:8081/projectname/rest/entity/path/entityDetails"
URL.response <- GET(URL,authenticate("username","password"))
```

Comment: You're trying to `GET` yourself? What are you trying to serve yourself? Do you have [a cert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS#Server_setup)?

Comment: Yes I have the Cert.... the full error is - Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  SSL: certificate subject name (Unknown) does not match target host name

Comment: Same issue, verifypeer doesn't seem to handle hostname mismatch for SSL cert.

Comment: same issue, I have installed certificates and able to do `GET` using the browser. Once I try to use `httr` it is not possible...

Comment: I have solved the problem by setting curl option `ssl_verifyhost` to FALSE.